# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline to trigger from changes in git directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I need code to jenkins scripted pipeline where I can say that pipeline is only allowed to trigger from changes in git directory and not from changes in whole repository to avoid useless triggers.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "git directory"?  Do you mean the actual ".git" directory in a repository or some other folder?  Can you share an example of your project's file structure and indicate the specific file/directory you want to watch for changes to trigger on?

Comment: What Git service do you use? If GitHub, here is one way of doing it: https://bjurr.com/jenkins-integration-on-steroids/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want your pipeline to run only when changes are detected for a specific sub directory in your Git repository, but not for changes only affecting files outside that directory.

Theoretically, the [PathRestriction](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) class that could be used with the `checkout` step would offer this through `includedRegions` and `excludedRegions`.

Unfortunately, this is not working for Git in Jenkins Pipeline, see [JENKINS-36195](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195).